# How to customise cell in FSCalendar?

Tags: ios, swift, fscalendar

I am trying to achieve Date Range selection using FSCalendar , and i am achieving that but the view i want that is not proper . so can anyone help for that ? I want output like below screenshot , but i am getting right now like this

My Current Output:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Viewcontroller.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var calendar: FSCalendar!

    var firstDate: Date?
    var lastDate: Date?
    var datesRange: [Date]?
    fileprivate let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    fileprivate let formatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return formatter
    }()
    let highlightedColorForRange = UIColor.init(red: 2/255, green: 138/255, blue: 75/238, alpha: 0.2)


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        calendar.delegate = self
        calendar.dataSource = self
        calendar.today = nil
        calendar.calendarHeaderView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        calendar.calendarWeekdayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.1)
        calendar.register(DIYCalendarCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        calendar.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        calendar.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}

extension ViewController {

    func configureVisibleCells() {
        self.calendar.visibleCells().forEach { (cell) in
            let date = self.calendar.date(for: cell)
            let position = self.calendar.monthPosition(for: cell)
            self.configureCell(cell, for: date, at: position)
        }
    }

    func configureCell(_ cell: FSCalendarCell?, for date: Date?, at position: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
        let diyCell = (cell as! DIYCalendarCell)
        // Configure selection layer
        if position == .current {

            var selectionType = SelectionType.none

            if calendar.selectedDates.contains(date!) {
                let previousDate = self.gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: date!)!
                let nextDate = self.gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date!)!
                if calendar.selectedDates.contains(date!) {
                    if calendar.selectedDates.contains(previousDate) && calendar.selectedDates.contains(nextDate) {
                        diyCell.selectionLayer.fillColor = highlightedColorForRange.cgColor
                        selectionType = .middle
                    }
                    else if calendar.selectedDates.contains(previousDate) && calendar.selectedDates.contains(date!) {
                        selectionType = .single // .rightBorder
                    }
                    else if calendar.selectedDates.contains(nextDate) {
                        selectionType = .single // .leftBorder
                    }
                    else {
                        selectionType = .middle //.single
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                selectionType = .none
            }
            if selectionType == .none {
                diyCell.selectionLayer.isHidden = true
                return
            }
            diyCell.selectionLayer.isHidden = false
            diyCell.selectionType = selectionType

        } else {
            diyCell.selectionLayer.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    func datesRange(from: Date, to: Date) -> [Date] {
        // in case of the "from" date is more than "to" date,
        // it should returns an empty array:
        if from > to { return [Date]() }

        var tempDate = from
        var array = [tempDate]

        while tempDate < to {
            tempDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: tempDate)!
            array.append(tempDate)
        }

        return array
    }

}

extension ViewController:FSCalendarDelegate,FSCalendarDataSource,FSCalendarDelegateAppearance {

    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, boundingRectWillChange bounds: CGRect, animated: Bool) {
        self.calendar.frame.size.height = bounds.height
    }

    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
        // nothing selected:
        if firstDate == nil {
            firstDate = date
            datesRange = [firstDate!]
            print("datesRange contains: \(datesRange!)")
             configureVisibleCells()
            return
        }

        // only first date is selected:
        if firstDate != nil && lastDate == nil {
            // handle the case of if the last date is less than the first date:
            if date <= firstDate! {
                calendar.deselect(firstDate!)
                firstDate = date
                datesRange = [firstDate!]

                print("datesRange contains: \(datesRange!)")
                configureVisibleCells()
                return
            }

            let range = datesRange(from: firstDate!, to: date)

            lastDate = range.last

            for d in range {
                calendar.select(d)
            }

            datesRange = range

            print("datesRange contains: \(datesRange!)")
            configureVisibleCells()
            return
        }

        // both are selected:
        if firstDate != nil && lastDate != nil {
            for d in calendar.selectedDates {
                calendar.deselect(d)
            }

            lastDate = nil
            firstDate = nil

            datesRange = []

            print("datesRange contains: \(datesRange!)")
        }
        configureVisibleCells()
    }

    func calendarCurrentPageDidChange(_ calendar: FSCalendar) {

    }

    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, cellFor date: Date, at position: FSCalendarMonthPosition) -> FSCalendarCell {
        let cell = calendar.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: date, at: position)
        return cell
    }

    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, willDisplay cell: FSCalendarCell, for date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
        self.configureCell(cell, for: date, at: monthPosition)
    }

    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, shouldSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) -> Bool {
        return monthPosition == FSCalendarMonthPosition.current
    }

    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, shouldDeselect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didDeselect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
        print("did deselect date \(self.formatter.string(from: date))")
        configureVisibleCells()
    }

}
```

DIYCalendarCell.swift

```
public var selectedColor = UIColor.init(red: 2/255, green: 138/255, blue: 75/255, alpha: 1)

enum SelectionType : Int {
    case none
    case single
    case leftBorder
    case middle
    case rightBorder
}
class DIYCalendarCell: FSCalendarCell {

    weak var circleImageView: UIImageView!
    weak var selectionLayer: CAShapeLayer!

    var selectionType: SelectionType = .none {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    required init!(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let selectionLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        selectionLayer.fillColor = selectedColor.cgColor
        selectionLayer.actions = ["hidden": NSNull()]
        self.contentView.layer.insertSublayer(selectionLayer, below: self.titleLabel!.layer)
        self.selectionLayer = selectionLayer

        self.shapeLayer.isHidden = true
        let view = UIView(frame: self.bounds)
        self.backgroundView = view;

    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
       // self.circleImageView.frame = self.contentView.bounds
        self.backgroundView?.frame = self.bounds.insetBy(dx: 1, dy: 1)
        self.selectionLayer.frame = self.contentView.bounds

        if selectionType == .middle {
            self.selectionLayer.path = UIBezierPath(rect: self.selectionLayer.bounds).cgPath
        }
        else if selectionType == .leftBorder {
            self.selectionLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.selectionLayer.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .bottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: self.selectionLayer.frame.width / 2, height: self.selectionLayer.frame.width / 2)).cgPath
        }
        else if selectionType == .rightBorder {
            self.selectionLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.selectionLayer.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topRight, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: self.selectionLayer.frame.width / 2, height: self.selectionLayer.frame.width / 2)).cgPath
        }
        else if selectionType == .single {
            let diameter: CGFloat = min(self.selectionLayer.frame.height, self.selectionLayer.frame.width)
            self.selectionLayer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: self.contentView.frame.width / 2 - diameter / 2, y: self.contentView.frame.height / 2 - diameter / 2, width: diameter, height: diameter)).cgPath
        }
    }

    override func configureAppearance() {
        super.configureAppearance()
        // Override the build-in appearance configuration
        if self.isPlaceholder {
            self.eventIndicator.isHidden = true
            self.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: have you found any solution?

Answer (score 3):

I just changed your code to support 3 (edited) shape layers:

```
weak var selectionLayer: CAShapeLayer? 
weak var roundedLayer: CAShapeLayer?
weak var todayLayer: CAShapeLayer?
```

One for the **range selection** , one for the **rounded layout** and one for **today**.

```
import FSCalendar
import UIKit

enum SelectionType {
    case none
    case today
    case single
    case leftBorder
    case middle
    case rightBorder
}

class CalendarCell: FSCalendarCell {

    private weak var circleImageView: UIImageView?
    private weak var selectionLayer: CAShapeLayer?
    private weak var roundedLayer: CAShapeLayer?
    private weak var todayLayer: CAShapeLayer?

    var selectionType: SelectionType = .none {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    required init!(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        let selectionLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        selectionLayer.fillColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        selectionLayer.actions = ["hidden": NSNull()]
        self.contentView.layer.insertSublayer(selectionLayer, below: self.titleLabel?.layer)
        self.selectionLayer = selectionLayer

        let roundedLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        roundedLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        roundedLayer.actions = ["hidden": NSNull()]
        self.contentView.layer.insertSublayer(roundedLayer, below: self.titleLabel?.layer)
        self.roundedLayer = roundedLayer

        let todayLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        todayLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        todayLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
        todayLayer.actions = ["hidden": NSNull()]
        self.contentView.layer.insertSublayer(todayLayer, below: self.titleLabel?.layer)
        self.todayLayer = todayLayer

        self.shapeLayer.isHidden = true
        let view = UIView(frame: self.bounds)
        self.backgroundView = view
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.selectionLayer?.frame = self.contentView.bounds
        self.roundedLayer?.frame = self.contentView.bounds
        self.todayLayer?.frame = self.contentView.bounds

        let contentHeight = self.contentView.frame.height
        let contentWidth = self.contentView.frame.width

        let selectionLayerBounds = selectionLayer?.bounds ?? .zero
        let selectionLayerWidth = selectionLayer?.bounds.width ?? .zero
        let roundedLayerHeight = roundedLayer?.frame.height ?? .zero
        let roundedLayerWidth = roundedLayer?.frame.width ?? .zero

        switch selectionType {
        case .middle:
            self.selectionLayer?.isHidden = false
            self.roundedLayer?.isHidden = true
            self.todayLayer?.isHidden = true

            let selectionRect = selectionLayerBounds
                .insetBy(dx: 0.0, dy: 4.0)
            self.selectionLayer?.path = UIBezierPath(rect: selectionRect).cgPath

        case .leftBorder:
            self.selectionLayer?.isHidden = false
            self.roundedLayer?.isHidden = false
            self.todayLayer?.isHidden = true

            let selectionRect = selectionLayerBounds
                .insetBy(dx: selectionLayerWidth / 4, dy: 4)
                .offsetBy(dx: selectionLayerWidth / 4, dy: 0.0)
            self.selectionLayer?.path = UIBezierPath(rect: selectionRect).cgPath

            let diameter: CGFloat = min(roundedLayerHeight, roundedLayerWidth)
            let rect = CGRect(x: contentWidth / 2 - diameter / 2,
                              y: contentHeight / 2 - diameter / 2,
                              width: diameter,
                              height: diameter)
                .insetBy(dx: 2.5, dy: 2.5)
            self.roundedLayer?.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect).cgPath

        case .rightBorder:
            self.selectionLayer?.isHidden = false
            self.roundedLayer?.isHidden = false
            self.todayLayer?.isHidden = true

            let selectionRect = selectionLayerBounds
                .insetBy(dx: selectionLayerWidth / 4, dy: 4)
                .offsetBy(dx: -selectionLayerWidth / 4, dy: 0.0)
            self.selectionLayer?.path = UIBezierPath(rect: selectionRect).cgPath

            let diameter: CGFloat = min(roundedLayerHeight, roundedLayerWidth)
            let rect = CGRect(x: contentWidth / 2 - diameter / 2,
                              y: contentHeight / 2 - diameter / 2,
                              width: diameter,
                              height: diameter)
                .insetBy(dx: 2.5, dy: 2.5)
            self.roundedLayer?.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect).cgPath

        case .single:
            self.selectionLayer?.isHidden = true
            self.roundedLayer?.isHidden = false
            self.todayLayer?.isHidden = true

            let diameter: CGFloat = min(roundedLayerHeight, roundedLayerWidth)
            let rect = CGRect(x: contentWidth / 2 - diameter / 2,
                              y: contentHeight / 2 - diameter / 2,
                              width: diameter,
                              height: diameter)
                .insetBy(dx: 2.5, dy: 2.5)
            self.roundedLayer?.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect).cgPath

        case .today:
            self.selectionLayer?.isHidden = true
            self.roundedLayer?.isHidden = true
            self.todayLayer?.isHidden = false

            let diameter: CGFloat = min(roundedLayerHeight, roundedLayerWidth)
            let rect = CGRect(x: contentWidth / 2 - diameter / 2,
                              y: contentHeight / 2 - diameter / 2,
                              width: diameter,
                              height: diameter)
                .insetBy(dx: 2.5, dy: 2.5)
            self.todayLayer?.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect).cgPath

        case .none:
            self.selectionLayer?.isHidden = true
            self.roundedLayer?.isHidden = true
            self.todayLayer?.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

---

And that's the final result.

---

[image]

---

You can check [this Github project](https://github.com/Enriquecm/CalendarCellExample) and see how it works.

> Important: You need to handle the day select/deselect states to make sure everything is working, the snipped code is just about the UI.

Comment: did you check that is it working ?

Comment: @Enrique its not working for me.

Comment: @Enrique its not working for me.

Comment: Please take a look at the answer updates.